# Xamarin Forms Android JSON.net Serialization

Tags: android, forms, xamarin, json.net

iOS is working perfectly, but Android builds are posting any empty JSON object "{}" to the webservice instead of the actual object with this line of code:

```
    myClient.Post(url,JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {
        param1: z,
        param2: y,
        param3: z
        }), 
    authkey);
```

Switching to a statically defined object fixes the issue. But why?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you should add new object for JsonConvert.SerializeObject(), like this, create new object:

```
class Model1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Then create new Model1 for JsonConvert.SerializeObject().

```
Model1 tem = new Model1() { Id=1,FirstName="cherry",LastName="bu"};
        string str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tem);

        Log.Debug("123",str);
```

Then it works fine, and I can get one string.

Comment: Thanks @cherry-bu, that is what we did, however, I was hoping to understand why?  The code works fine on iOS and other places with C#, but it does not work properly on Android devices.

Comment: Do you try my code at your side? I use my code at Android and Ios, it works fine, but I have some error when using your code:`JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {
        param1: z,
        param2: y,
        param3: z
        })` because JsonConvert.SerializeObject() need one object that you define.